# loading HTML Content from another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is given:
Website A, Website B, Snippet.js

I dont have access to Website A the only thing we got a is a loaded Javascript Snippet, which is on Website B.

I got full access to Website B and to Snippet.js

Website A HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div> <script src="WebsiteB/snippet.js"/>
```

Website B HTML Contains a index.html which has Text in it.

snippet.js:

```
$('#container').load('WebsiteB/index.html');
```

I want that the snippet.js loads the content from Website B into the div container on Website A but I get a CORS error.

Is there any other solution to do this?

Comment: You cannot make cross-domain JS calls without CORS or JSONP due to same-origin policy.

Comment: You could use an iframe to load the content of the other page maybe?

Comment: So  basically I cant use JSONP to get the content from the other Website?

Comment: I already thought about using an iframe but its no possible solution for me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: The other website must actively allow you to communicate with it, either via CORS headers or a jsonp API of some kind.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Now I got something to search for. Ill update an answer when I got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PHP include:

```
<?php
include("http://www.google.de");
?>
```

or PHP file_get_contents:

```
<?php
print file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
?>
```

Comment: Since I only can add a Javascript Snippet to Website A I think PHP is no possible choice for me.

Comment: You could add JavaScript to A.COM that calls CORS enabled website B.COM/get.php?url=C.COM